# IllegalStateException in Twitter Integration

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate twitter in Android and following Twitter4j library. I have given the right consumer key and secret and have added the needed lines in manifest. Have added the Callback_URL in twitter. At first, I was able to login successfully but later it started throwing IllegalStateExcetpion.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.feb_1twitterintegration;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXX";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXXX";
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken = new RequestToken(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    EditText sts;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            return;
        }
        // Check if twitter keys are set
        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            return;
        }
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        findViewById(R.id.login).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        loginToTwitter();
                    }
                });
        findViewById(R.id.tweet).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        String status = sts.getText().toString();
                        if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                            new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please enter status message",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            final String verifier;
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                //verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                System.out.println(verifier);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Request token: "+requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    System.out.println("after login");
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                    System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());
                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit();
                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
                    findViewById(R.id.login).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.editText1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.tweet).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();
                    Log.e("UserID: ", "userID: " + userID + "" + username);
                    Log.v("Welcome:",
                            "Thanks:"
                                    + Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username
                                            + "</b>"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), 1000)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void loginToTwitter() {
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.run();
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    builder.setUseSSL(true);
                    builder.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);

                       /*configurationBuilder.setOAuth2TokenType(getOAuth2Token().getTokenType());
                       configurationBuilder.setOAuth2AccessToken(getOAuth2Token().getAccessToken());*/
                    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                    twitter4j.Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Request token: "+requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        System.out.println("Req Token: "+requestToken);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken
                                        .getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        System.out.println("Request Token in already logged in twitter: "+requestToken);
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);
                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    // Clearing EditText field
                    sts.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat :**

```
02-03 14:01:54.407: D/Network(21178): NETWORKnAME: WIFI
02-03 14:01:54.407: I/System.out(21178): Request Token in already logged in twitter: OAuthToken{token='oauth_token', tokenSecret='oauth_token_secret', secretKeySpec=null}
02-03 14:01:54.447: D/libEGL(21178): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-03 14:01:54.467: D/libEGL(21178): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-03 14:01:54.487: D/libEGL(21178): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-03 14:01:54.487: D/libEGL(21178): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-03 14:01:54.567: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(21178): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-03 14:01:54.577: D/OpenGLRenderer(21178): Enabling debug mode 0
02-03 14:01:54.627: D/OpenGLRenderer(21178): has fontRender patch
02-03 14:01:54.657: D/OpenGLRenderer(21178): has fontRender patch
02-03 14:01:56.128: I/System.out(21178): Request Token in already logged in twitter: OAuthToken{token='oauth_token', tokenSecret='oauth_token_secret', secretKeySpec=null}
02-03 14:01:56.168: I/System.out(21178): Request token: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=oauth_token
02-03 14:01:56.168: W/dalvikvm(21178): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa9228)
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-65119
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178): java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuth(TwitterBaseImpl.java:403)
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:298)
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178):    at com.example.feb_1twitterintegration.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:166)
02-03 14:01:58.741: D/OpenGLRenderer(21178): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-03 14:01:58.751: D/memalloc(21178): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52368000 size:3072000 offset:1536000
```

And the line where it implies for error is as follows :

```
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
```

Any idea on what might be causing this issue to appear suddenly. I have been working on this for the past 2 days but this error has appeared from nowhere. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not expose your secret Twitter keys on SO. I have edited the question and removed them now, but I suggest you create a new key set now...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pretty straighforward. Logcat tells you this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-65119
02-03 14:01:56.178: E/AndroidRuntime(21178): java.lang.IllegalStateException: OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied
```

You need to declare your `Twitter twitter` object as a class variable, because you are setting the consumer and secret keys only to an instance of the object, but when you are requesting the auth token, you get a new instance of it, that doesn't have the configuration for the keys set.

`private static Twitter twitter;`

Then use this twitter object in the `private void loginToTwitter()`, and replace this:

`twitter4j.Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();`

with

`twitter = factory.getInstance();`

where your twitter object is now a class iVar.

Here is a sample from my own implementation, that should help you:

```
public class TwitterRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {

final String TAG = getClass().getName();

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_DENIED = "denied";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "appnameoauth://twitterLogin";

private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;
private AccessToken accessToken;

/** Progress */
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    authenticate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}   

/**
 * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the request token).
 * The callback URL will be intercepted here.
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
        //check if user did cancel the twitter auth
        final String error = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_DENIED);
        if (error==null)
            getTwitterAccessToken(uri);
        else {
            // Login failed
            Toast.makeText(TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this, getString(R.string.twitter_login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //user did not authenticate
            finish();
        }
    } 
    else {
        // Assume error: such as no connection
        Toast.makeText(TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this, getString(R.string.twitter_login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

/**
 * Gets our token data once we obtain our accessToken from the asyncTask
 */
private void uploadToken() {
    // upload data to our server
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this, getString(R.string.generic_wait), getString(R.string.generic_sync), true, false);
    // Getting user details from twitter
    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();

    //upload code to our server (irrelevant to question)
}

private void getTwitterAccessToken(Uri uri) {
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this, getString(R.string.generic_wait), getString(R.string.twitter_logging_in), true, false);
    final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
    // get the Token from Twitter       
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> tokenTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this.accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            hideProgress();
            if (TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this.accessToken==null){
                hideProgress();
                finish();                   
            }
            else
                uploadToken();
        }
    };

    tokenTask.execute();
}

/**
 * Starts the oAuth request with our callback URL
 */
private void authenticate() {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Global.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Global.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();

    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    twitter = factory.getInstance();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                    TwitterRequestTokenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
}

/**
 * Hides the progress bar
 */
private void hideProgress() {
    try {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

}

Also you need to make sure this activity is declared in your manifest as single task and set to listen to your custom oAUTH callback url:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".twitter.TwitterRequestTokenActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="twitterLogin"
                android:scheme="appnameoauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried that but no use. Still the same error persists.

Comment: Can you show me your code after your did what I suggested?

Comment: TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
     twitter = factory.getInstance(); is what my code contains now where twitter is a class variable of type Twitter.

Comment: Should I give the same callback URL in my twitter Callback_URL column that you have specified in your code ?

Comment: Well this is a sample. You should use your own, replacing appname, with your app's name. just make sure to replace it in both the manifest and the activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46683/discussion-between-san-and-lefteris)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that same issue. its blocking on your ui. u just try it in asynctask. u just call that code inside a asynctask.

requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
or

like this,

```
class TwitterLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();                
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL))
            {
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                try 
                {
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = loginPrefs.edit();
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit();

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());


                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();
                    Log.e("UserID: ", "userID: "+userID+""+username);

                    Log.v("Welcome:","Thanks:"+Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
    }
```